# How to store and pass the user input value using <button> tag in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I'm trying to get the value from the user and show it on the screen, but it seems my code doesn't pass the value from my Input class to the main class. Nothing happens when I click Submit. here is the code for my main .js class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UserInput from './UserInput/UserInput';
import UserOutput from './UserOutput/UserOutput';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    userName : 'Masood'
  }

  manipulator = (event) => {
    this.setState(
      {userName : event.target.value}
    )
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UserOutput userName = {this.state.userName}/>
        <UserInput changed={this.manipulator}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the code for the Input class:

```
import React from 'react'

const userInput = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={props.changed}>
            <input style={style} type="text" value={props.userName}/>  
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>   
        </form>
        </div>
    )
};

export default userInput;
```

and here is the output class:

```
import React from 'react'

    const userOutput = (props) => {
        return(
        <div>
         <p> Here is a test from output file.</p>
         <p>Username is {props.userName}</p>
        </div>
        )
    };

export default userOutput;
```

Sorry for a too long code for a too small question, but I thought I should include everything.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the main problem is that you try to submit a value, but if you `console.log` the `event.target.value` it is equal to null.

You should have an event handler for `onChange, when you change the text in the input, f.e:

```
const UserInput = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={props.userName} onChange={props.changed} />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Hope this will help even more: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: I actually tried using onChange={props.changed} in the input tag, but it outputs the data to the screen without even using the submit button. The reason I want to do this using the submit button is that I'm practicing taking the data and storing it in a variable.

Comment: If you want, you can create a separate variable to store the data, and onSubmit just rewrite it. Because you need to store the current value which was already submitted and the value, which is being written

Comment: That's the question actually. I'm using onSubmit={props.changed} which should trigger the manipulator() method in the main js class to set the state to a different username, but it doesn't.

Comment: It won't actually, because the onSubmit doesn't store any variable which is you typing in the input. You should create a totally separate state variable and change it, and on the onSubmit, just do something like: `this.setState({ pickedValue: typedValue });`